# Get the Largest Count of Consecutive Value

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have this table that records win and lose. Let us say this is my table

```
create table test(
  col1 int not null
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

it has 10 rows :

```
0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1
```

1=Win and 0=Lose. I want to get max count of the consecutive win and lose. For this example, the max count for consecutive win is 3 and for lose is 2. How can I get my desired result? I'm not sure where to start with this one. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
create table t1 (
 colid int not null auto_increment,
 col1 int,

 primary key(colid)
);

insert into t1(col1) values (0);
insert into t1(col1) values (1);
insert into t1(col1) values (1);
insert into t1(col1) values (1);
insert into t1(col1) values (0);
insert into t1(col1) values (1);
insert into t1(col1) values (1);  
insert into t1(col1) values (0);
insert into t1(col1) values (0);
insert into t1(col1) values (1);


select 
a.col1,
max(a.rn)
from (

        select 
        x.col1,
        if (@prev = col1 ,@current := @current + 1,@current := 1 ) rn, @prev := col1
      from t1 x , (select @prev := - 1 , @current := 1) v  
      order by x.colid
      ) a
group by a.col1
```

this one works the way I see the results.. Is there anything I should consider? I only have knowledge on basic joins. I haven't fully understand the query as of now..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
create table t1 (
col1 int 
);

insert into t1 values (0);
insert into t1 values (1);
insert into t1 values (1);
insert into t1 values (1);
insert into t1 values (0);
insert into t1 values (1);
insert into t1 values (1);  
insert into t1 values (0);
insert into t1 values (0);
insert into t1 values (1);

select t.col1,
   max(t.rn)
  from (
select t1.col1,
if (@prev = col1 ,@current := @current + 1,@current := 1 ) rn,
   @prev := col1
 from t1,(select @prev := - 1 ,
              @current := 1) v  
 ) t
 group by t.col1;
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nQzq4KtftfdZxxjxk1G1Ve/1)

Comment: It may work, but the order of the rows in a table should not be trusted without an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: The result is visually correct? It is random.

Comment: not sure why this one got down voted.. this one works.. i even added and auto-increment column and an order by.. I don't have 15 reputation to accept it as answer.. i will be editing my question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't trust that table to work.  A table, by definition, is unordered.  SQL is free to return the ones and zeros in any order.

So...  You need to have another column that can be used to sort on -- a date or a game-number, or something.

Then you can ask the question because you can do a `SELECT ... ORDER BY ...`.

The rest is messy.  You should consider, instead, writing the algorithm in your favorite programming language other than SQL.

1. Add an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and index it.
2. Do a self join on a.id = b.id-1 to find where the transitions are (0 to 1 or 1 to 0)
3. Extract only the transition ids.
4. Repeat the auto_in game, but instead of finding transitions, subtract the old ids.  This gives you the run lengths.
5. `SELECT ... ORDER BY .. LIMIT 1` to find the longest run, together with some of the history of where it came from.